# Как заставить тег audio воспроизводить mp3 в браузере Mozilla?

Tags: аудио, mp3, конвертация, формат, web-audio

Браузер Mozilla не воспроизводит mp3 файлы в теге `<audio>` . Можно ли как-нибудь его заставить воспроизводить? Понятно, что можно переконвертировать в другой формат, но это не то. Есть ли какой-нибудь гуманный способ?

Comment: В firefox с некоторыми типами файлов, так что пока нормально через html5 работают только некоторые типы, они сами на этот счет говорят использовать плагины. Так что на данный момент вроде никак без конвертации на стороне сервера не обойтись

Comment: а как добавить плагин? для тега audio

Comment: FF47 32bit + Win7 32 bit отлично воспроизводится mp3 в теге `audio`.

Comment: странно, почему тогда такая штука у меня в windows10 не воспроизводится в mozilla и в хроме кстати тоже <audio controls><source src="Against.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

Comment: В инструментах разработчика бразуров в консоль и во вкладку Сеть загляните. Какие сообщения там есть про файл Against.mp3? И возможно про тег audio?

Comment: в хроме пишется "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". А в Firefox "Не удалось загрузить ни одного кандидата на ресурс. Загрузка медиа приостановлена."

Comment: Путь до файла указан не верно. Браузер его просто загрузить не может.

Comment: странно, html файл на рабочем столе и mp3 файл на рабочем столе

Comment: а не гоню, точно, в отдельной папке лежал. работает

Comment: А есть какой-нибудь способ все-таки, чтобы, например, какой-нибудь аудио файл, который не понимает firefox заставить его воспроизводить? То, что тут советовалось плагин, как я понимаю имелось ввиду, чтобы только на моем компьютере работало? Мне нужно, чтобы если выложу html страницу в интернет это работало и на других компьютерах - в общем заставить воспроизводить в интернете